# jQuery programatic button click causes cursor to move

Tags: javascript, jquery

My issue is this: when a user enters a certain hotkey combo (ctrl-b-b), I want to programatically click a button. I've done that with jQuery

```
$(myButton).click();
```

However, the user is typing into an editor, and the button click causes the cursor in the editor to move out of the editor. I would like to be able to click the button without moving the cursor at all.

Is that possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of clicking a button to execute a function, just call that function directly. Is anything preventing you from doing that?

Comment: @andreim I feel a little stupid..good one :) Yes that works. If you want to create an answer I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: I created an answer for your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking a button might run a handler or might submit or reset a form. Instead of clicking the button programatically, just call the handler directly. In case is a submit or reset button, just call `form.submit()` or `form.reset()` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(myButton).trigger( "click" );
```

Comment: Add some code like that we can understand the more the problem